# How to make table row group color (even - odd) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, tabular

How to make table in jQuery like:

[image: this pic :]

I know this is simple, but I hope, someone can help me.
With the good logic.

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service, in order to get help with your problem, you have to show us your own attempt.

Comment: Also that screenshot you linked isn't really a good example of even/odd row styling... What exactly do you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`

You can use modulo (`%`) to check if number is even or not.

```js
$(function() {
  $("td:nth-child(4)")                    /* Select the 4th child td */
    .filter(function() {                  /* Filter even numbers using % */
      return !($(this).text() % 2);
    })
    .parent()                             /* Select the parent - tr */
    .css({"background-color": "red"});    /* Apply CSS*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Orders</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TEXT</td>
    <td>TEXT</td>
    <td>TEXT</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TEXT</td>
    <td>TEXT</td>
    <td>TEXT</td>
    <td>56</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TEXT</td>
    <td>TEXT</td>
    <td>TEXT</td>
    <td>44</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TEXT</td>
    <td>TEXT</td>
    <td>TEXT</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TEXT</td>
    <td>TEXT</td>
    <td>TEXT</td>
    <td>97</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for yor recomended, its work i use module for make the logic :D